# Unable to change the src of an img element using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write a piece of code which replaces an image with another image on page load. But unfortunately it does not happen so. The second image does not load. i only see an icon with a cross mark after pageload. Please have a look at the below code and let me know what's wrong. Thanks in advance.

```
<html>    
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">    
function loadImage()    
{
   document.getElementById('ab').src ="C:\Users\Gagan\Desktop\green.png";    
}
</script>    
</head>    
<body>    
<img Id= "ab" src="C:\Users\Gagan\Desktop\red.jpg" onload="loadImage()">    
</body>    
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future viewers of this question, I would recommend the [unobtrusive JavaScript pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) for this, where the `onload` is done completely in JavaScript:

```
<html>    
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var img = document.getElementById('ab');    
function loadImage()    
{
   img.src ="C:\\Users\\Gagan\\Desktop\\green.png";    
}
img.onload = loadImage;
</script>
</head>    
<body>    
<img id="ab" src="C:\Users\Gagan\Desktop\red.jpg" alt="" />    
</body>    
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, backslash is the escape character. If you want to include it in a string, you have to escape it using itself:

```
document.getElementById('ab').src = "C:\\Users\\Gagan\\Desktop\\green.png";
```